# 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WindowsFormsApp1.Form1+AssgnData'

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

Hi all I think I know the issue to my problem but not fully how to resolve it.  I think the issue has to doe with my JSON file having brackets around it and I need to remove them?

Here is what is in the JSON file:

```
[{"EMPLID":"102104","NAME":"t,g"},{"EMPLID":"108160","NAME":"m,t"},{"EMPLID":"127186","NAME":"t,m"}]
```

I have two forms, one that pulls data from an oracle table and serializes it into a file, and one that is supposed to deserialize it and then populate a data set.

Once I select my data and put it into a data table, I serialize using the below:

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\assign.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    //serialize object directly into file stream
    serializer.Serialize(file, dt);
}
```

My form then closes and the file is supposed to be deserialized using the below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Form frm2 = new Form2();
        Form frm3 = new Form3();
        if (this.Visible == false)
        {

            this.Hide();        
            MessageBox.Show("closing");
            this.Show();
            //AssgnData movie1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AssgnData>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\assign.json"));
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\assign.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                AssgnData movie2 = (AssgnData)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(AssgnData));
            }
        }
    }
    public class AssgnData
    {
        public string EMPLID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse it will fail, you need to parse as `(IEnumerable<AssgnData>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IEnumerable<AssgnData>))` and not `(AssgnData)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(AssgnData)`. Remember, you are trying to deserialize array of objects and not just a single object.

Comment: using IEnumberable is causing me a conversion type failure.
"an explicit conversion exists, are you missing a cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json matches a collection of `AssgnData` and not a single item. Therefore you should deserialize it as an `IEnumerable<AssgnData>`:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\assign.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    IEnumerable<AssgnData> movie2 = (IEnumerable<AssgnData>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IEnumerable<AssgnData>));
}
```

If using `Newtonsoft.Json` it looks like:

```
string json = "[{\"EMPLID\":\"102104\",\"NAME\":\"t,g\"},{\"EMPLID\":\"108160\",\"NAME\":\"m,t\"},{\"EMPLID\":\"127186\",\"NAME\":\"t,m\"}]";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AssgnData>>(json);
```

Comment: using IEnumberable is causing me a conversion type failure. "an explicit conversion exists, are you missing a cast

Comment: @Spartanias - I tested the code above and it should work. On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: I was missing the IEnumberable for the variable movie2

Comment: @Spartanias - BTW, I'd personally go with the `Newtonsoft.Json` that is generic and avoid the casting

Comment: The package right? i do have that.The below is what I was missing. I still had it as movie2 = 
when i needed
IEnumerable<AssgnData> movie2 =

Comment: @Spartanias - Yes the package

Comment: I marked yours as the answer. thank you for the quick resolution